# How to disable a cell of a GridView row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a `GridView` control whose first two columns have buttons. When the row is being created, I want to check if the sixth column text is "Locked" or not. If yes then the button in the first cell should not be visible.

The first two columns of the `GridView` looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something as below to hinde the button control form the cell...

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[5].Text=="Locked")
            {
                (e.Row.FindControl("idofButton1") as Button).Visible=false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

create a CSS class

```
.invisible
{ 
   display:none;
}


protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[5].Text=="Locked")
        {
              e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "invisible"
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Make sure this is an event for `GridView1.RowDataBound` so a better name for this will be `GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){...}`